# Locate store using name wordpress plugin

Tags: php, wordpress

I have checked many plugins of store locator such as SimpleMap , wordpress store locator , store locater plus, puzzy's store locator etc. All this plugin provide search using address , city and Zipcode. i want plugin that can also locate store by its Name.
I have tried to customize all plugin but i failed.

Please help if anyone know about it.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

This function is not available in free plugins maybe available in Premium plugins. I found that, plugins of these type only search from Address, City or ZIP. They don't have functionality for search using name. These plugins create custom post type for location and from its custom fields of address, city and zip this search work.

Many Directory themes like [Directory](http://templatic.com/app-themes/directory-theme), [GeoPlaces](http://templatic.com/app-themes/geo-places-city-directory-wordpress-theme/) etc. have this function.

**From Me:** Use these plugins, they works well, only not have one function.

Comment: let me check his Thanks for reply

Comment: i dint find map setting there

Answer (score 1):

Store Locator Plus Enhanced Search add-on pack will add the search by name feature to the Store Locator Plus base plugin:
http://www.charlestonsw.com/product/slp4-enhanced-search/

Comment: what if i dont want to buy it

Comment: Build your own.   The hooks and filters are documented on the website.  All of the premium add-on packs are built using those hooks and filters, so if you want to save $50 you can build your own "search by name" feature.   http://www.charlestonsw.com/support/documentation/technical-documentation/

Answer (score 1):

You can embed store locator to your Wordpress website, here's the link http://codecanyon.net/item/super-store-finder/3630922

It's pretty easy to install with a few clicks, once done, you can just to paste the embed code (like youtube) when editing your Wordpress web page, here's a screenshot of my store locator https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZDAo9.jpg

You will also have an admin area to manage your stores and import Bulk stores from CSV file